# Gaussian blur with opencv in ios

Tags: android, ios, opencv, blur, gaussian

I am trying to make a gaussian blur with opencv in ios. I have already included opencv into my app, but I don't know how to call it so that it makes a gaussian blur.

In Android I call it like this:

```
Mat source = Highgui.imread(filepath, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Mat destination = new Mat(source.rows(),source.cols(),source.type());
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(source, destination, new Size(45, 45), 0);
Highgui.imwrite(getDir().getPath() + File.separator +"Gaussian45.jpg", destination);
```

Is there something similar in iOS too?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[By the looks of things](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html#opencviosimagemanipulation), You have to convert it to a cv::Mat, then you can use the normal guassian blur c++ method and then convert it back to ULLImage

The above link demonstrates how to convert from and to the two image types. Once you have converted it to cv::Mat you simply [use this method](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#gaussianblur):

```
void GaussianBlur(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, Size ksize, double sigmaX, double sigmaY=0, int
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a part of the solution. First I had to rename my file from xx.m to xx.mm so that opencv can work correctly, but I don't know why. Finally I called the function like that: cv::GaussianBlur(cvImage, cvImageGauss, cvSize(45,45), 0);

Comment: @jps90 OpenCV is a C++ library. Objective C is only compatible with C. To use C++ you need objective c++ (standard extension .mm).